# What's the replacement for writing to Android's LOCATION_MODE secure setting?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-settings

Android contains [the `LOCATION_MODE` secure setting](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#LOCATION_MODE) for controlling whether location is enabled via GPS, network, or both. This setting was deprecated in API 28. The documentation lists replacements for reading this value and being notified when it's changed, but is silent on a replacement for writing to this value. If I'm writing an app that wants to change location sources, what's the new non-deprecated way to do it?

Comment: There might be no replacement at all.

Comment: I suspect they won't give you anymore the ability to change it, instead it will be changed by user manually from settings.

Comment: @Daniel I don't believe that Android Pie has a setting for the user to change this manually.

Comment: this might meanwhile be fully abstracted by the `FusedLocationProvider`, which automatically selects the most accurate source, depending on device capabilities and granted fine or coarse location permission. One the one hand, that's one thing less to worry about, but on the other hand, it slightly limits the possibilities (it's not the first time I've seen new Android features killing off applications, which used to be working).

Comment: @MartinZeitler that would definitely break what I want to do. In particular, this is/was useful to put the device in "battery saving mode" where it won't use the GPS receiver, which there seems to be no other way to do.